# Sitecore publish to separate instance master database

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have 2 instances of Sitecore, I want to be able to publish from the first instance (instance A) to the second instance (instance B) some of the content. (fyi, I cannot use the instance A for the website for instance B for business purposes, they need to be separate)

I created a publish target in instance A to publish to the master database of instance B, but the items do not show up in the content tree of instance B. However, the items have been published to the master database of instance B as I wanted.

Can you publish from one master database to another master database?

I tried to publish a folder which was using Sitecore's folder data template so I defiantly know that the data template was there when I published.

Using Sitecore 6.6

Comment: Do you mean publish from master to 2 different instances of web? It's not possible to publish from master to master, although you could "Move an item to another database" via the Control Panel.

Comment: One thing to try, maybe the parent item needs to have the same Id. Try adding a default Sitecore folder at the root level next to home, example: Sitecore/Content/YourTestFolder.

Comment: You're running into the same problems as I blogged about here. http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2009/05/working-with-multiple-content-databases.html. To stay on the supported path, you need to re-think your implementation of this.

Comment: This is only a temporary solution as it is for migration, once the content has been migrated it will be locked for the user to edit on instance A, they will have to use instance B - but the migration is planned to take a while, this is why we are looking for this path.  I have used the Transfer to database in the control panel and it seems to copy to the master database of instance B as intended.

Comment: If I wanted to publish from instance's A master db to Instance's B master db  I would just change the connectionstrings in the instance's A to point the "web" connectionstring to the master of Instance B and publish my items. O think that would be one of the possibilities to try out on a test environment ;)!

Comment: @Younes Publishing from instance A master to another database will not act in a true master to master publish, it will only publish the latest version of each publishable item, i.e. a regular master to web publish. I'm not sure what the intention of the OP was exactly though.